# Get and change listview adapter items without onclick handler

Tags: android, listview

I have an customized the listview adapter as per my need.

What am i trying to acheive ??

My application will send serialno through an external reader and

**1.** If the serial no is already present in the listview the imageview associated with it should change. 
**2.** If the serialno is not available then it should be added on listview (This part is done. )

Now i want to check the serial no with existing items on the list view and change its imageview . How do i acheive it ??

Also i want to get all the listview items with an particular imageView  ??

**activity_scan.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/scan_loc_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

**activity_listview.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scan_img_view"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/scan_img_view"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scan_serial"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>       

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ScanItem.Java**

```
public class ScanItem {

    private int imageId;    
    private String serial;

    // Getter and Setter Methods 
    ............

}
```

**ScanAdapter.java**

```
public class ScanAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ScanItem> {

    Context context;

    public ScanViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,List<ScanItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtSerial;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        ScanItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtSerial = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scan_serial);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scan_img_view);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtSerial.setText(rowItem.getSerial());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
        return convertView;
    }


}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
ScanAdapter assetListAdapter = new ScanAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.activity_listview, items);  // items contains array of ScanItem objects
ListView androidListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.scan_loc_list);
androidListView.setAdapter(assetListAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I foundout the answer myself

```
int count = androidListView.getAdapter().getCount();

        String[] listData = new String[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ScanItem sc = (ScanItem) androidListView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
            // sc will have all the required data
        }
```